# Compile error when trying to import web3swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, go-ethereum, web3swift

I am trying to import `web3swift` into one of my `Swift` files, but get the compiler error

> No such module 'web3swift'".

The import statements look like this:

```
import Geth
import web3swift
```

In my pod file, I have:

```
pod 'web3swift', :git => 'https://github.com/MercuryProtocol/web3.swift.git', :branch => 'master'
```

I have also tried the following fix which hasn't worked:

- Go to `Build Settings`
- Search `Framework Search Paths` (case sensitive)
- Double click on `<Multiple values>`
- Click the `+`
- Add $(SRCROOT) and set it to recursive

Comment: Are you openning `YourProject.xcworkspace` file or `YourProject.xcodeproj`?

Comment: I'm opening the .xcworkspace file

Comment: Select the `Pods` project in the Project Navigator.  In the right-hand pane, select the `web3swift` target.  Select Build Settings.  Search for Product Module Name.

Comment: And then...? It has web3sweift selected but am I supposed to changer a setting as there doesn't seem to be one?

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, you are probably using another repo. Please check that your actual version is `0.7.0`.

#### Installation

web3swift is available through [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org). To install
it, simply add the following line to your Podfile:

```
pod 'web3swift', git: 'https://github.com/matterinc/web3swift'
```

Run `pod install` from the command line

It should work fine after that.
If you still have problems, feel free to open an issue:
https://github.com/matterinc/web3swift/issues